# How to get the return filter array data in angular js controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

I'm using the custom filter for my application.

```
div class="cust-post" ng-repeat="post in newsfeeddata | customFilter:companyFilters"
```

In the above code customFilter return the array data i need to use that array data into my controller.

I don't know how to retrieve that array data.

Anyone please assist me.

Comment: You can assign a filtered value to a property: `ng-repeat="post in (filteredData = (newsfeeddata | customFilter:companyFilters))"`. You could also use the `as` notation: `ng-repeat="post in newsfeeddata | customFilter:companyFilters as filteredData"`

Answer (score 1):

Try `as` keyword within `ng-repeat`, then you can access to filtered array via `$scope.array`:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items=[
      {name:'A'},
      {name:'BA'},
      {name:'CB'},
    ];
    $scope.test = function() {  
      $scope.out = $scope.array.map(x => x.name).join(', ');      
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type='text' ng-model='search' ng-init='search = "A"'/>
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat='item in items | filter: search as array'>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <input type='button' ng-click='test()' value='Test'/> 
  <hr/>
  {{out}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter function which return array:

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function( newsfeeddata, companyFilters ) {
      return items.filter(function(element){
        return companyFilters >= element.minValue;//Compare the values
      });
    }
});
```

In controller:

```
var filteredData = $filter('customFilter')(newsfeeddata, companyFilters);
```